# How to set a System.Type property for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, types

I've got a class that has a property of type Type. How can I set this for unit testing?

Example class:

```
public class School
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type SchoolType { get; set; }
}
```

I can mock the Name but I'm not sure how to mock the SchoolType property.

Example test:

```
string expectedName = "Richmond";
var expectedType = ???

var school = new School();
school.Name = expectedName;
school.SchoolType = expectedType;

Assert.AreEqual(expectedName, school.Name);
Assert.AreEqual(?, school.SchoolType);
```

Comment: `typeof()` - e.g. `typeof(string)`

Comment: If you are doing this in the first place, it's almost certainly a bad idea anyway. Why are you using `Type` anyway? What benefit does that give you over, say `string` or an `enum`?

Comment: Have to agree with @DavidG `Type` seems like an odd choice, specially when the implementation for it to be always correct could be `public Type SchoolType => this.GetType();` now the property `SchoolType` will always be the type of the instance and it can never be incorrect. https://dotnetfiddle.net/vfsTnM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, In here `HighSchool` is a class that you want to assign to `SchoolType` property.

```
string expectedName = "Richmond";
var expectedType = typeof(HighSchool);

var school = new School();
school.Name = expectedName;
school.SchoolType = expectedType;

Assert.AreEqual(expectedName, school.Name);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedType, school.SchoolType);
```